# Extend Firebase User

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

After authenticating the user and updating the `FirebaseUser` table, I would need to save other extra data such as age, gender, address etc. I would like to use the Realtime Database by creating a user node and hooking to the `FirebaseUser` through UID. Is my way of working correct? I would be grateful if somebody can help me understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common practice in Firebase is to create for your user a `helper class` (`model class`, `POJO class`) and this the corect way to achieve this:

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String gender;
    private String address;
    private String email;

    public User() {}

    public User(String name, int age, String gender, String address, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.address = address;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

    public int getAge() {return age;}    
    public void setAge(int age) {this.age = age;}

    public String getGender() {return gender;}
    public void setGender(String gender) {this.gender = gender;}

    public String getAddress() {return address;}
    public void setAddress(String address) {this.address = address;}

    public String getEmail() {return email;}  
    public void setEmail(String email) {this.email = email;}
}
```

Because you need a unique identifier for your users, the `uid` is the perfect choice. You can get the `uid` using the following line of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseUser.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

To insert data into you database, you need to create an object of User class. So please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
User user = new User("John", 25, "male", "101 Main Street", "john@email.com");
usersRef.child(uid).setValue(user);
```

In this you can simply use the public setters and getters to add/get data from your Firebase database.

Your database will look like something like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    --- users
          |
          --- uid1
               |
               --- name: "John"
               |
               --- age: 25
               |
               --- gender: "male"
               |
               --- address: "101 Main Street"
               |
               --- email: "john@email.com"
```

Comment: I have used the `uid` as an identifier between users. As you can is used in the line `messagesRef.child(uid).setValue(user);`. If you need that `uid` as a field in your pojo class, just add it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

That's correct, to get the [current user's unique ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_a_users_provider-specific_profile_information) you can use:

```
FirebaseUser.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

And you can then store details about a user into the Firebase Realtime Database using that unique ID as a key, something like:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseUser.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String userId = user.getUid();

DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

HashMap<String, Object> userDetails = new HashMap<>();
message.put("name", "P. Sherman");
message.put("age", 50);
message.put("gender", "male");
message.put("address", "42 Wallaby Way, Sydney");
message.put("email", user.getEmail());

messagesRef.child(userId).setValue(userDetails);
```