# Firebase android : How to saving further details such as address, account level, date of birth etc?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

We can use this code for create basic profile info is automatically saved by firebase. But, how can I save further details if I want some more information?

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
    String name = user.getDisplayName();
    String email = user.getEmail();
    Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();

    // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to
    // authenticate with your backend server, if you have one. Use
    // FirebaseUser.getToken() instead.
    String uid = user.getUid();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to extend the `FirebaseUser` object and add some more informations inside the class.
If you want to store the same object in Firebase you need to create a new branch (e.g `Users`) in Firebase and save the `User` object.

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47178476/5382017) if you want more details about it.

Comment: I send 1 day for this problem. Really helpful. Thank you